# Backpropagation over inputs python

Tags: python, backpropagation, gradient-descent, bidirectional

I have developed a Bidirectional Recurrent Neural Network(BRNN) for predicting values given in input a vector with 5 entries.

For example:

```
 X_test=[0,2,3,4,154.8]
```

it returns a predicted value having the form:

```
y_predict=354.45
```

Now my desired target for **y** is

```
y_target=540.11
```

I can achieve the target value with prediction over BRNN when I have a different input, in fact for example:

```
 X_test=[0,2,3,4,109.65]
```

the BRNN returns:

```
y_prediction=540
```

So basically, just changing the last value of the input I achieve my desired prediction. 
I need an algorithm, separated from the BRNN, that can learn which is the best input (just considering the first 4 entries as fixed and varying the last entry of the input) minimising a cost function

```
 (y_prediction-y_desired)^2
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps simulated annealing?

Comment: I don't know. do you have any examples for my case?

Comment: No, have you tried something that we can help you with? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.